# Account created using Web3js wont recieve tokens from Metamask

Tags: web3js

I am using web3js to create a local account using the following function

```
    function makeaccount() {
        var account = web3.eth.accounts.create();
        console.log(account);
        var walletprivate = account["privateKey"];
        var phppasswallet = "THE_PASSWORD";
    }
```

This functions generates an account locally but I can even access the balance of this address from **Already Deployed Contract Token** using

```
contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call().then(function (balance) {
            $("#balance").html(balance);
        });
```

However when I try to send tokens from Metamask to this address. It keeps spinning and balance of the address created using makeaccount is always zero. I am using a private network and have setup metamask and web3js to use the localhost network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the account created by`web3.eth.accounts.create()` creates the address without `0x` prefix. My script wasn't addressing this and metamask would get the address without `0x` prefix and I was unable to send the transaction.

Comment: A good gotcha! This is a common mistake and roots from the fact that JavaScript does not have native big number support or good binary data support. It is documented here https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-accounts.html#privatekeytoaccount